# Is there a .row substitution?

Tags: html, css

I have two .row sections in my HTML page, which I want different CSS for, yet for my CSS, they both fall under .row, and all aspects in the .row are spread through both of them. How do I individualize these .row's to have separate CSS, without losing the .row characteristic for one of them?

Please advise if this makes no sense whatsoever... :P

My problem in HTML + CSS

```
<style>
.row {
            margin: 0 5px;
            position: relative;
        } 
.row {
            padding: 0 30px;
        }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img width="100%" src="https://image.ibb.co/gweBdQ/image.jpg" alt="Annas Blog">
             <div class="caption">
            <h3><font face="Calibri"><strong>The Blog!</strong></font></h3>
            <p><small>View Anna's Blog! That's why you're here anyway... right?</small></p>
            <p><a href="BLOG.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Blogs!</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

And the separate .row

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item text-center"><label><font class="text" align="center" face="Indie Flower" size="6">See Anna's People!</font></label>
                    <br/>
                    <img style="vertical-align:middle" width="299" height="299" class="img-circle" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/880522424705441799/EPujLjrD_400x400.jpg" />
                </li>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

And the padding on the second .row effects the first .row.

Without .row padding

[image: no padding]

With .row padding

[image: no padding]

You see, its much smaller?

Comment: Can you please post a snippet?

Comment: Add an additional class to one of them and style that one in css

Comment: You will get something like class="row custom-row"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I think you want something like this:

```css
.row {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.divA {
  color: red;
}

.divB {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row divA">
  <p> I'm Div A</p>
</div>

<div class="row divB">
  <p>I'm Div B</p>
</div>
```

They both have `font-size:30px` but have different colors